# How to connect multiple Docker containers in AWS ElasticBeanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Docker multicontainer configuration meant to run in a ElasticBeanstalk environment.

The EB environment runs in a VPC, in a public subnet, has a single load-balancer and a single instance bound.

It looks like all of the containers are running fine but they cannot communicate with each other even though i defined them as linked containers.

What do I need to do to get all of these containers talking to each other?

My Dockerrun.aws.json looks like this:

```
"containerDefinitions": 
    [
        {
            "name": "proxy",
            "image": "nginx",
            "essential": true,
            "memory": 128,
            "portMappings": 
            [
                {
                    "hostPort": 80,
                    "containerPort": 80
                }
            ],
            "links": 
            [
                "webapp"
            ],
            "mountPoints": 
            [
                {
                    "sourceVolume": "nginx-conf",
                    "containerPath": "/etc/nginx/conf.d",
                    "readOnly": true
                },
                {
                    "sourceVolume": "awseb-logs-proxy",
                    "containerPath": "/var/log/nginx"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "webapp",
            "image": "jetty",
            "memory": 2048,
            "essential": true,
            "portMappings": 
            [
                {
                    "hostPort": 8080,
                    "containerPort": 8080
                }
            ],
            "links": 
            [
                "mongodb"
            ],
            "mountPoints": 
            [
                {
                    "sourceVolume": "jetty-webapp",
                    "containerPath": "/var/lib/jetty/webapps",
                    "readOnly": false
                },
                {
                    "sourceVolume": "awseb-logs-webapp",
                    "containerPath": "/var/log/jetty"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "mongodb",
            "image": "mongo",
            "memory": 1024,
            "essential": true,
            "portMappings": 
            [
                {
                    "hostPort": 27017,
                    "containerPort": 27017
                }
            ],
            "mountPoints": 
            [
                {
                    "sourceVolume": "mongodb-data",
                    "containerPath": "/data/db",
                    "readOnly": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Check your security groups. You may need to open some ports. Usually, that is the reason my EB can't communicate with the outside world.

Comment: It seems like i can get to Nginx, i get a cannot connect to upstream server.  In the WAR, i see it cannot connect to Mongo.  Since Jetty and Mongo run behind Nginx on the same instance do I still have to open ports on the security group beyond 80?

Comment: As a note I have these SG's:
- vpc: default VPC security group (all traffic)
- net:  special security group (80/22)
- dev-vpc: EB security group (80/22)
- dv-lb: EB load balancer group (80)

Comment: Usually, you have to add each security group to the list of incoming traffic so they can communicate with each other. Also, if you have a DB, you need to enable DB ports inside the SG.

Answer (score 0):

In 2017, Use the container definition: [`links`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definitions) with the name of the Docker container you want to connect to. Docker's built-in network bridge will make the connections from there.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, it had nothing to do with the security groups since all I am exposing publicly is 80 for the Nginx proxy.

It came down to using the names in my /etc/host (webapp, mongodb), instead of the IP, that were created for the containers.

This fixes my connection from Nginx to Jetty and Jetty to MongoDB.

Comment: How did you change the /etc/host file and where did you change it? the host file in the host machine? in each container? Can you please share a more concrete example? as I'm having the same problem, it would be nice to have a more concrete answer.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, how did you do it? please comment here, your answer is not complete! I have the same problem

Comment: It has been a while since I posted this but if I recall, in my configuration files (nginx, application config, etc.) I used the names of the services - webapp, mongodb, etc. instead of the assigned IP of the container.  You may have to refresh my memory, is the problem your services are not talking to each other?